# How to rearrange order of divs with 12 bootstrap columns width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs being one above the other.

[image]

When the window width goes below 992 pixels, I want b to be above a, so I want to rearrange them vertically.

I am trying to do that with bootstrap. The result becomes like this:

[image]

Why?

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="a col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-md-offset-0">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="b col-xs-12">
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent
{
  width: 100px;
}

.a
{
  background: #faa;  
}
.b
{
  background: #afa;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24tt6xgL/5/

Other things I have tried:

- pushing the a-div 12 and pulling the b-div 12 columns with col-md-push-12 and col-md-pull-12.
- Only pushing the a-div, not pulling the b-div.
- pushing the a-div 6 columns, pulling the b-div 6 columns

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe that you can't do this with bootstrap

Comment: Is it like 12 columns is too much or that I cannot get a wrap around effect?

Comment: This is just because a is before b in your html, you can't put b above a ony with bootstrap

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible with Bootstrap. It doesn't work with 12 units as it consumes the entire row. The only option would be to dup on of the columns and use the responsive util classes to show/hide as needed: http://codeply.com/go/tWg9U3qSVz

Comment: I agree that it probably can't be done in Bootstrap. Another option would be to use a media query and flexboxes. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ajae0qd/1/)

Comment: What about if you put b first with offset12 and with javascript you delete the offset class when you resize the window like window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 900px)" );

Comment: If you include javascript, you produce a solution that falls outside the problem description! :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this would be to use the classes like hidden-*. In this way, you would have duplicate code, but it would quickly achieve what you would like to do and stay within Bootstrap.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="b col-xs-12 visible-xs visible-sm">
      b
    </div>
    <div class="a col-xs-12">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="b col-xs-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see here, the .b div has been duplicated, but never appears twice: For md and lg screens, the top .b div would be hidden and the bottom one would be shown. For xs and sm screens the opposite is true.

Of course, this solution is not perfect, the maintenance of the code is more of an effort, so if these divs are much longer than in the example code, it is probably worth trying to play with the CSS, but if the code is short, it would be a good solution.

It's also worth noting that duplicating the .a div above and below the .b div instead is an equivalent solution.

Comment: This is @Skelly solution. At least mention it